# how to reboot a frozen FreeBSD server from the serial console?

Tags: freebsd, reboot, serial-console, magic-sysrq

Linux has the "[magic sysrq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_sysrq)" to reboot frozen machines remotely, and it works over the serial console, but what about FreeBSD? Is there a way to send a "control-alt-delete" to FreeBSD servers on serial consoles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a kernel with the debugger option compiled in you can use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>. From there you can `call boot(0)` or `panic`.

Chapter 10 of the [FreeBSD developers handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug-online-ddb.html) explains this in a lot more detail.

So much for more or less the same as SysReq via a keyboard. On the serial console, you need to send the [break signal](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/serial-uart/index.html#idp75089712) and have the `options BREAK_TO_DEBUGGER` enabled. But "*it is not the default since there are a lot of serial adapters around that gratuitously generate a BREAK condition, for example when pulling the cable*".

Comment: chapter 10 of the freebsd handbook is about [printing](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/printing.html), did you mean chapter 10 of [the developers handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug-online-ddb.html)?

Comment: Aye. I did. I was linking to both the normal handbook and the lin you posted, then I cleaned it up. I guess I got sidetracked during that. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: so i tried it, and it doesn't work from the serial console, it seems that you need to send a BREAK and have the `options BREAK_TO_DEBUGGER` in your kernel config.

Comment: These day, you can also control the state of support for breaking into the kernel debugger with `sysctl` - the `debug.kdb.break_to_debugger` setting.  There is also an alternate key sequence that is handy when your console connection does not support the serial break condition.  See the `debug.kdb.alt_break_to_debugger` sysctl setting or `options ALT_BREAK_TO_DEBUGGER` in the kernel config.  See also `ddb(4)` and `gdb(4)`. The alt break method supports key sequences to enter the debugger, perform an immediate reboot, or generate a panic.